# Wordpress Mailchimp Form custom checkbox

Tags: forms, wordpress, plugins, custom-fields, mailchimp

I'm using the [Mailchimp subscription plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp/) for wordpress (v. 1.2.13). It's all ok, I just need to add a checkbox to accept privacy terms. I've created that field through the [Mailchimp form managment](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/advanced-customization-of-mailchimps-sign-up-forms), it shows and works in the form except that **I need to define it as required**. There is no option for that in mailchimp, i tried to add a simple "required" attribute in html, but it didn't work (as expected).

Any suggestion?

I've also spotted that Mailchimp define if that field is required in an array/place called `$var['req']` that is someway connected with the field name. But I can't find where can I access this array or how to add my custom field to that.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the link to your post where the Advanced management for forms is to be accessed in MailChimp. [Here it is again](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/advanced-customization-of-mailchimps-sign-up-forms)

But well, its only available to paid users. You can customize every bit of the form in that place.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="acceptterms" />
```

Then presuming your MailChimp 'Subscribe' link has an ID of 'mailchimpsubscribe' then you can do the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> jQuery('#mailchimpsubscribe').click(function() { if (jQuery('#acceptterms').prop('checked') == false) {return false; } }); </script>
```

So basically you're adding a click event to your MailChimp submit button and checking if the terms checkbox has been ticked - if not, return false so the click doesn't complete.